# Strange symbols when using printf in C

Tags: c, string, matrix, printf

I have a question about `printf` in C. I try to print a matrix as a string, but instead of the matrix I get many of these symbols:
[image]

I have no idea what it is and found no information on internet. Can someone explain me what it is and how to avoid it?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int mat[9][9] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
                     {7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
                     {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3},
                     {9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
                     {6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                     {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2},
                     {8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
                     {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4},
                     {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1}};

    char matrix[81];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            matrix[i * 9 + j] = (char)mat[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < 81; a++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", matrix[a]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like a mark to represent non-printable characters. Redirecting your output to a file and using hex-dumping tool (for example `od -Ax -t x1`) or binary editor to look at that may give you some more information of waht is your output.

Comment: My guess is you wrongly used `%c` instead of `%d`.

Comment: You are probably trying to print a number value  instead of a string - but without any code to see what you ae doing it is al speculation.

Comment: You should post the code.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: You are trying to print integer values like `1`, `2`, `3` as characters.  Now, it's true, characters are represented in C as small integers, but the characters with values 1, 2, and 3 are all nonprintable *control characters*.  You want to change your printout to `printf("%d\n", matrix[a]);`.  Or, you could try filling your array with values in the range 48-57, 65-90, and 97-122 (since those are values that *do* correspond to ordinary printing characters in ASCII).

Comment: @SteveSummit ah the ASCII table, thank you

Comment: It isn't clear what kind of result you are expecting.

Comment: `matrix[i*9+j]=(char)mat[i][j] + '0';`

Comment: @Cosinus its works but I do not understand why? can you explain please?

Comment: Most of the other comments have pretty much explained this already.. That is a conversion from number zero, to character '0' (it has a value of '0', in ASCII that's 0x30).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `matrix[i * 9 + j] = (char)mat[i][j] + '0';`
>
> > *It works but I do not understand why? can you explain please?*

It works because of the way characters are encoded, in ASCII every character is encoded into a 7-bit decimal value. The digits codes are in the contiguous interval from `48` which is `'0'` to `57` which is `'9'` (contiguous digit encoding is required in any encoding, as opposed to the alphbetic characters, ***e.g.*** EBCDIC), so effectively what you are doing is adding `48` to the integer you want to print.

For instance, `printf("%c", 0);` will print the character that is represented by the decimal value `0`, that is a non-printable control character, and that's the reason you get that strange output, characters with codes from `0` to `31` are control-characters and have no printable representation.

If you add `'0'`, ***i.e.*** `printf("%c", 0 + '0');`, the output is correct, you are effectively adding `48` to `0`, and `48` is the code for the digit `'0'` and that's what's printed, `1 + '0'` will be `49`, which is the character code for the digit `'1'` and `1` will be printed, the same for the other digits.

This is a trick for when you want to convert decimal values to their  ASCII representation, or any other encoding for that matter, simply adding `'0'` to the value, `[0-9]`, you want to print.

Because in C the characters are identified by their codes and `char` types are really integer types, you could print the `int` array directly, if you want to avoid copies:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", mat[i][j] + '0');
    }
}
```

**Note:**

If you just want to output the digits, you could also fix it by using `%d` specifier instead of `%c`. The practical result is the same.